# Android -Stuck with ListView Item

Tags: java, android

I'm Developing an Android Application .In that Application ,I've set a list view each has One Imageview,Progressbar(InVisible) and two buttons .

```
plAdapter = new PlayAdapter();
         lv1.setAdapter(plAdapter); 
}

private static class AccessoriesViewHolder {
Button play,download;
ProgressBar pb;

}

private class PlayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.toArray().length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return a;
        //return al[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


         holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.design, parent, false);

            holder = new AccessoriesViewHolder();
            holder.play = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
            holder.download = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dwnld);

            ((Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play)).setOnClickListener(mBuyButtonClickListener);
            ((Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dwnld)).setOnClickListener(mBuyButtonClickListener);
           ((ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

           // convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else 

        {

            holder = (AccessoriesViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        /*
         * The Android API provides the OnCheckedChangeListener interface
         * and its onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean
         * isChecked) method. Unfortunately, this implementation suffers
         * from a big problem: you can't determine whether the checking
         * state changed from code or because of a user action. As a result
         * the only way we have is to prevent the CheckBox from callbacking
         * our listener by temporary removing the listener.
         */


        return convertView;
    }
}

/**
 * Quickly shows a message to the user using a {@link Toast}.
 * 
 * @param message The message to show
 */
private void showMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private OnClickListener mBuyButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = lv1.getPositionForView(v);

        // int dummy=position;
            showMessage(listsong[position].toString()+"");


            ((ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
};

protected AdapterView<ListAdapter> getListView() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

If I click one of the Button in a row ., the Progress bar Must be visible in that row.

The problem is, if i click a button the progress bar on other row gets visible but not corresponding row.

Comment: Rakesh, You have to modify the logic of getView. Create boolean Array as data and OnClickListener fetch index on click is done on list item and on getViewMethod progressbar will shown if that element number is set to be true in boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add an OnClickListener for the button in the getView() method in your ListView Adapter and inside the OnClickListener set the visibility of the ProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `getView` method like that:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


     holder = new AccessoriesViewHolder();

     convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.design, parent, false);

     holder.play = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
     holder.download = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dwnld);

     ((Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_play)).setOnClickListener(mBuyButtonClickListener);
     ((Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dwnld)).setOnClickListener(mBuyButtonClickListener);
     ((ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

     return convertView;
}
```